# Gson: Mapping multiple json objects to a single object

Tags: android, json, gson, mapping

Suppose we have this simple json:

```
"Book":
{
    "title": "Hello world",
    "metadata": 
     {
         "author": "Jeff"
     }
}
```

Is there an easy way to ignore the metadata object and put author directly into a books object using gson? Should i use a deserializer for that or is there an easier way?

I need a class like this:

```
public class Book
{
    private String title;
    private String author;

    //...
}
```

Comment: yes, you need to write custom deserializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Deserializer. Something like this :

```
public class BookDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Book> {

  @Override
  public Book deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {

    final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    final String title = jsonObject.get("title").getAsString();
    JsonElement metaElement = jsonObject.get("metadata");
    final String author = metaElement.get("author").getAsString();

    final Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle(title);
    book.setAuthor(author);
    return book;
  }
}
```

How to use it:

```
sGson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Book.class, new BookDeserializer())
        .create();
```

Note : I prefer to use Constant instead of hardcoded strings but it's just for the example here ;)

Comment: i did it using the entryset to add the pairs to the parent object. But this is also a possible solution so i will mark it as resolved, thanks